# Error when opening a new Spring Boot Project using SpringToolSuite

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring.I downloaded SpringToolSuite  3.7.2 and i am trying to create a simple SpringBootApplication. 
I go to File->New Spring Starter Project,Select Type as Maven project and Under dependencies i selected Web and click on Finish. I get an error on my parent tag in pom.xml and also not able to see the maven dependency libraries.
I tried right clicking on the project->Select Maven->Update Projects-> Checked all boxes and Update but does not work. I also tried cleaning the repository under C:{User}.m2 clean and rebuild the project but did not work for me.[Screenshot of the STS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYVzy.png)

Project build error: Non-resolvable parent POM for com.example:demo:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not transfer artifact org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:pom:1.4.3.RELEASE from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org and 'parent.relativePath' points at no local POM

Please tell me what am i missing.
Below is my  pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringApplication1</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: If you have maven installed (not the one that is shipped with Eclipse) then try to build the project from command line `mvn clean compile -U`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply mate @Ralph . I tried this already but it does not seem to work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error suggests that you are not able to connect to (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2).

Please check your maven settings.xml (Window -> Preferences -> Maven -> Global/User Settings):

If you are using proxy, you need to add it on your settings.xml.

Something like this :

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <proxies>
    <proxy>
      <id>myproxy</id>
      <active>true</active>
      <protocol>http</protocol>
      <host>proxy.somewhere.com</host>
      <port>8080</port>
      <username>proxyuser</username>
      <password>somepassword</password>
      <nonProxyHosts>*.google.com|ibiblio.org</nonProxyHosts>
    </proxy>
  </proxies>
  ...
</settings>
```

As you can see on https://maven.apache.org/settings.html.

If you are not using proxy, be sure that you don't have any proxy configuration on your settings.

Comment: Thank you for the help @Cleto .I suppose this could be the problem as i had seen a similar post on stack. But upo checking i found that i do not have the settings.xml in my project.Is this something i need to add manually or have i missed something out while project creation?

Comment: settings.xml need to be placed in my local m2(maven)repository if i am not mistaken.is this correct? also what would proxy-id be?

Comment: You can use your ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml or ${maven.home}/conf/settings.xml. Proxy-id would be any name that you want: 'myProxy', 'proxyOfMyCompany', etc..